# Loop through excel files in a folder and open it without reference to filenames

Tags: file, loops, directory

I want to loop through excel files in a folder and extract information. My problem is that the file names of my excel files are in Vietnamese, so when I use the Dir function to loop, it does not work. How can I loop through files in a folder and open them without specifically referring the names.

I also try the GetFolder method but it doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks for your help.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
   Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, File As Variant
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set MySource = MyObj.GetFolder("C:\Excel")
   For Each File In MySource.Files
        Set wb = Worksbooks.Open(File)
   Next File
End Sub
```

Comment: What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: The code above results in the error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set on the Set MySource line.

Comment: When I use the Dir function to loop through the folder, it cannot open the file and result in the error of can not find the file name in the folder because the file name is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a DIM for MyObj, but you don't initialize it before it is used. You should probably have a SET MyObj = something